# Fastest supervized Tutorial: Precision Very Low

Tags: text, text-classification, fasttext, precision-recall

Hi I am running the same tutorial on the supervised module of fastest in the tutorial

https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html

In the tutorial we get the below results:

```
model = fasttext.train_supervised(input="cooking.train", lr=0.5, epoch=25, wordNgrams=2, bucket=200000, dim=50, loss='ova')

model.test("cooking.valid", k=-1)
(3000L, 0.702, 0.2)
```

Where the precision is 0.702 and recall is 0.2.

But when I run the same tutorial at my I get the below results:

```
(3000, 0.003146031746031746, 1.0)
```

Has something changed with the newer version of fastext which is not documented yet.

I am using fasttext version 0.9.2

Comment: Why do you use the string "cooking.valid"? This is not the full validation set used in the tutorial.

Comment: Hi can you refer where cooking.valid is not used. Did you check the documentation. I think you are confusing the predict and test module.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same tutorial on the supervised module of fastest in the tutorial"? Can you link to specifically what you're doing? If your run the code once, & get `(3000L, 0.702, 0.2)`, what do you then do different to get instead `(3000, 0.003146031746031746, 1.0)`? (You're not getting that one immediately-subsequent runs on the same system/version/data/etc, are you?)

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion I have updated the question with the link to the tutorial I am saying that in tutorial of fasttext the results (3000L, 0.702, 0.2) are shown but when I run the same tutorial I get the different results instead 3000, 0.003146031746031746, 1.0)